# Product variations attributes as cart items shows up differently in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, cart

I noticed that woocommerce is threating different product attributes differently *(see screenshot)*.

[image: Screenshot of Woocommerce Checkout]

The attributes of the first product are added only with numbers after the dash. The attributes of the second product is listed below the product title.

I can't figure out why this happens.

How to make all product attributes look like the one of the first product?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They can be many reasons. Before woocommerce 3 variation attributes where displayed as cart item meta data like "Seirin J + tube" … Now the variable products created under WooCommerce version 3+, display their attribute values in the title, like "Seirin B + tube"…

But hopefully there is some ways to unify this using some dedicated hooks.

1) Display attributes values in cart items title for all cases *(this one is for you)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_true' );
```

2) Remove attributes values in cart items titles for all cases and display them as separated `attribute` / `value` pairs under the title.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.