# Display product attributes for variations everywhere (backend + frontend + email notifications) in woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

How do I display a product category and it's variations everywhere on orders (backend + frontend + email notifications)?

I am writing about this question:
[Display product attributes for variations on cart page in woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732882/display-product-attributes-for-variations-on-cart-page-in-woocommerce-3)

I found one problem after applying these changes:
[Product variations attributes as cart items shows up differently in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871261/product-variations-attributes-as-cart-items-shows-up-differently-in-woocommerce)

After adding a line:

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false');
```

It stops displaying the attributes on the back-end order page.

After removing this line, it shows the attributes on the back-end order page but stops displaying them in the cart page.

I need to get that display everywhere on orders (backend + frontend + email notifications).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', function( $should_include_attributes, $product ){
    // Only on front-end
    if( ! is_admin() )
        $should_include_attributes = false;

    return $should_include_attributes;
}, 20, 2 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.