# Show product attributes on WooCommerce basket page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I look after a website (https://www.artyapple.com/) and the product attributes aren't showing up when viewing the basket.

I have tried the 'WooCommerce Show Attributes' plugin and it didn't work. I've also tried several bits of code found on this website and nothing has worked.

I'm running a new version of WordPress and WooCommerce but my theme is really out of date - the owner will not update the theme.

I'd really appreciate any help or advice. Thanks,

Paul

Comment: How old is the basket template? Maybe a fresh one from the plugin into a child theme would help.

Comment: Thanks Josh but still no luck with it.

The only piece of code that actually made any difference to the page was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732882/display-product-attributes-for-variations-on-cart-page-in-woocommerce-3

It successfully displayed the product categories but it's the attributes I need.

Comment: I've modified that answer given in the link to use attributes, ill post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The following filter should get the attributes for each product in the cart and add their names to an array. Then the array is output as comma seperated values below the product name in the cart page.

Modified from: [Display product attributes for variations on cart page in woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732882/display-product-attributes-for-variations-on-cart-page-in-woocommerce-3)

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'customizing_cart_item_data', 10, 3);
function customizing_cart_item_data($item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{
    $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);

    $attribute_names = array();

    // Get product attributes
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    if (!empty($attributes)) {
        foreach ($attributes as $attr) {
            $attribute_names[] = $attr->get_name();
        }

        $item_name .= '<p class="item-category" style="margin:12px 0 0; font-size: .875em;">
            <span class="values">' . implode(', ', $attribute_names) . '</span>
        </p>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```